# Integration of modules into yii project

Tags: php, yii

I am a newbie to YII.

I have a project which is divided into different modules. I have copy pasted one module from one system into mine and I'm unable to open that new module

It shows the following error-
Alias "invmgmt.InvmgmtModule" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable.

I have also included this module in my main.php file.

Comment: try checking for path,uppercase and file permission.

Comment: Thanks! It was the problem with file permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must include it in 'modules' part of yii config file:

config path is:

> protected/config/main.php

Comment: Yea I have included! The problem was with file permissions